# Understanding intel SUB instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

I am currently trying to deepen my understanding of assembly code and I am stuck since weeks with a seemingly simple instruction :

```
sub al, BYTE PTR [ebp+4]
```

**Assuming `eax = 0x11223300` and `BYTE PTR [ebp+4] = 0xaa` what is the value of `eax` after the above instruction ?**

From what I understand, `al` can only affect the last byte in `eax` (`0x00` in this case) so the program tries to compute `0x00 - 0xaa`. But the result being negative, I don't get if the result would simply be `0x00` or if numbers are automatically transformed to a negative number, in which case `0xaa` can itself be considered as a negative value which would imply we are trying to compute `0x00 - (-0x2a)` = `0x2a`

I found [in the SUB documentation](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sub) that

> The SUB instruction performs integer subtraction. It evaluates the
>   result for both signed and unsigned integer operands and sets the OF
>   and CF flags to indicate an overflow in the signed or unsigned result,
>   respectively. The SF flag indicates the sign of the signed result.

But it only describe some behaviour of the flags and I can't figure out how to look for more about those in such a specific case.

Comment: `sub` doesn't saturate to 0, it wraps.  Just like `uint8_t result = 0U - 0xaaU` in C.

Comment: `sub` does not know whether you are requesting signed or unsigned subtraction, as it is used for both.  Since `sub` is used for both, it doesn't concern itself with negative numbers or answers: it simply computes a value and lets you decide whether you care about what kind of overflow might have happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of it in two different ways, and they both give the same result.

As unsigned, the result is computed mod 256. So `0x00 – 0xaa mod 0x100 = 0x56`.

As signed, `0xaa` represents `–0x56`. (Not `–0x2a` as in the question.)
So, `0x00 – (–0x56) = 0x56`.

Answer (score 3):

> From what I understand, al can only affect the last byte in eax ...

This is correct.

> But the result being negative ...

Now it becomes complicated.

Just like most CPUs, x86 does not distinguish between unsigned integers and "twos-complement" signed integers.

This means that `0xaa` may mean 170 or (-86) and it's the task of the programmer or the compiler to interpret the value (if `0xaa`means 170 or -86).

This is possible if only the low bits of a calculation are considered. Example:

```
0 + 170   = 0x000000AA
0 + (-86) = 0xFFFFFFAA
```

or:

```
0 - 170   = 0xFFFFFF56
0 - (-86) = 0x00000056
```

In both results above, the low 8 bits are equal.

So for an instruction that will only modify the low 8 bits, it does not care if `0xaa` means 170 or (-86).

The x86's `SUB` instruction would write the low 8 bits of the result to the register and "throw away" the upper 24 bits.

The CPU sets the 4 bits in the "flags" register to pass additional information about these 24 bits to the program.

> if the result would simply be 0x00

Some CPUs support instructions that operate like this: The result of a subtraction is 0 if the "correct" result would be negative.

However, such CPUs typically have two different `SUB` instructions: One that calculates like the `SUB` instruction of the x86 and another instruction that will saturate the result to 0.

Comment: *The CPU sets the 4 bits in the "flags" register to pass additional information about these 24 bits to the program.*  I don't like this way of describing it.  It makes it sound like a wider computation really happened, or could be misleading.  I'd prefer to say "about borrow output and signed overflow of that 8-bit subtract".  Also, 2 of the FLAGS bits (SF and ZF) only depend on the low 8 result, not the carry/borrow output.  And I guess you're ignoring PF and AF which is fine, but "the 4 bits in FLAGS" isn't great phrasing.

Comment: @PeterCordes *It makes it sound like a wider computation really happened.* Indeed, if we performed a "wider computation" manually with the pencil on paper, the result of subtracting (or adding) two n-bit numbers would be an (n+1)-bit number. On x86 all n+1 bits are calculated: n bits will be placed in the destination register and one bit will be placed in the "carry flag". So the CPU actually performs a "wider calculation". However, it is true that the CPU will not perform a 32-bit calculation when adding two 8-bit numbers.

Comment: Ok yes, of course it computes the carry-out.  All I meant was wider than *that*; as you say not 32-bit or 64-bit.  And equally importantly, 2 of the major 4 flag bits (SF and ZF) don't come from outside the operand-size.